# Cassandra cluster looses performance in one node

Tags: docker, cassandra

I have a two-node Cassandra cluster running with docker. The nodes have 12 cores each and 32Gb of RAM. More details:

- Cassandra Version 3.11.0
- Docker Version 17.09
- The database and commit-logs are kept in separate volumes.
- memtable_offheap_space_in_mb: 4096
- concurrent_compactors: 4
- disk_optimization_strategy: spinning
- concurrent_writes: 64
- concurrent_counter_writes: 64
- compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec: 256
- MAX_HEAP_SIZE="6G"
- Compaction strategy: TimeWindowCompactionStrategy
- The rest remains as default

I set a third machine to perform a load test, sending large amounts of information to the cluster. I monitor the throughput and I like what I see (about 400 messages per second being consumed by each node) and this stays like this for hours.

**Problem:** After approx. 1 day, the throughput drops substantially in one of the nodes (about 60/s) whereas the other keeps doing fine, and this state does not change. The resource usage (e.g. cpu) also drops proportionally, which gives the idea that the node just decided to become lazy.

In the cassandra logs the following messages are often seen: "Maximum memory usage reached (512.000MiB), cannot allocate chunk of 1.000MiB" and "Writing large partition ", which I suspect to be related to the problem but not really sure.

I realize that I may not be providing enough information for a diagnose, but truth is that I don't have it. Therefore I'm hopping that this may be straightforward to someone or that he/she experienced something similar in the past.

Any help or advice is most welcome. Thank you for your attention.

Best regards.

Comment: "Maximum memory usage reached (512.000MiB), cannot allocate chunk of 1.000MiB" means you have reached the file_cache_size_in_mb limit. This option can be changed in cassandra.yaml so I would investigate this. You say your nodes have 12 cores and 32GB memory each. That sounds like they could be bare metal machines so why are you using docker? If they are both running on the same machines then you have to make sure they are not "stepping on each others toes" so to say. The large partition warning is printed whenever a partition goes over compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb value.